# How to change the name of an index entry

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

I'm using the package imakeidx to index a book I'm writing, but I have run into a small issue. I tried scanning the documentation to see if there was a way to change the name of what is being indexed but I must've missed it.

For instance, say I want to have "union of two sets" in the index, but what I've written in the text is "union of A and B", can I have something like \index[union of two sets]{union of A and B}? I tried this syntax but it didn't work so I'm wondering if there is a way to make it work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. When you use `\index{something}` then the `something` is normally not printed in the document, only in the index. So for example the minimal document `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
union of A and B\index{union of two sets}
\printindex
\end{document}` does what you want. Is that not the case for your setup? If not then you should post a minimal version of how you create a document with index entries, then we can check for approaches for your issue.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot more sense, I just realized I was using the package wrong. I was only writing \index{union of A and B} and not "union of A and B\index{union of two sets}". Thanks for clarifying, this actually answers my question perfectly.